# Test latlng in Firestore

Tags: testing, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to test the **GeoPoint** object from Firestore, here's the code that I have:

`request.resource.data.latLng is latlng;`

and here's the portion of my test:

```
await firebase.assertSucceeds(userLocationRef.set({
            "name": "Some name",
            "locationString": "Some location",
            "objectID": "objectID",
            "phoneNumber": "Some phone number",
            "latLng": {
                "latitude": 9.82,
                "longitude": -82.877
            }
        }))
```

With this code my test doesn't pass, I there a way to test a **GeoPoint** from Firestore?

Comment: How do you know that your test does not pass because ot the GeoPoint? Can you post the minimum reproduction steps for your issue ?

Comment: The test is not passing because it shows that it didn't pass, and those are the steps, I've added the code that is needed in order to replicate the issue.

Comment: Have you tried constructing a new GeoPoint() object according to your coordinates and using the [isEqual()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.GeoPoint#isequal) method to achieve the relevant comparison?